# How to get Facebook Page analytics data

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, analytics, facebook-page, facebook-insights

I need to access to Facebook Page analytics data on a given date range like the ones shown below for public pages without having access to page insights.

Using FQL all I can get is fan count for today using the page id.

SELECT name, fan_count, description FROM page WHERE page_id=xxxxxxxxx

Fql queries or php code will be helpful.

This report https://app.simplymeasured.com/viewer/h9p8rvrec5qwfsqjig2rrc6nwcuxq6ic6ykvewkd/455130

or a much simpler report like this one.

http://www.zuumsocial.com/sites/all/themes/sooper_synopsis/custom/images/hp/screen-leaderboard.png

Answer (score 3):

The API supports historical data for your own pages and apps and this is [clearly documented](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights)

Once you have the `read_insights` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) you cna do this with Graph API or FQL

For example, to retrieve the like count for each day over the last month, this Graph API insights query would show the results:

`/[PAGE ID HERE]/insights/page_fans/lifetime?since=1 month ago`

The result for one of my pages is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "255463667838002/insights/page_fans/lifetime", 
      "name": "page_fans", 
      "period": "lifetime", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 52, 
          "end_time": "2012-05-21T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 52, 
          "end_time": "2012-05-22T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 53, 
          "end_time": "2012-05-23T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 53, 
          "end_time": "2012-05-24T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 53, 
          "end_time": "2012-05-25T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
        {
          "value": 53, 
          "end_time": "2012-05-26T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
// Snipped more of the same
      ], 
      "title": "Lifetime Total Likes", 
      "description": "Lifetime The total number of people who have liked your Page. (Unique Users)"
    }
```

If you're asking about someone else's page or app, the answer is no - you'd need to utilise a third party service who had already cached the information when it was publicly available (i.e a polling service)